# Hibernate - criteria.list() return only one record but expected more

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I got a pretty simple query to do.

The problem is that criteria.list() return only one record but expected more.

My criteria is this;

```
final Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Provider.class)
        .createAlias("user", "u")
        .add(Restrictions.eq("u.sourceId", "oc-5002"))
        .setCacheable(true)
 .setComment("AccountDaoImpl.findAllProvidersByUserSourceIdAndPracticeSourceId");
```

and then i'm return this:

```
criteria.list()
```

Why do I get single result while I got multiple results in DB ?

Comment: To ask the obvious, how are you determining that this data actually exists in the DB?  If it isn't there, but you still expect it to be there, is its possible that some Hibernate session has not yet been committed when you run the above criteria query?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the data exists and committed

Comment: Check, that you have exactly 'oc-5002' sourceId column value in target rows by direct query. There can be leading or trailing spaces, that you don't see somehow.